# How to Set Offset and limit for My Native SQL query using SpringJPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have created query to fetch Offset and Limit values from Local host URL.But I am getting below error.

```
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM mail_user u  WHERE u.mailaddr LIKE ? AND u.userName LIKE ? AND u.sendflag =? AND (u.info01 LIKE ? OR u.info02 LIKE ? OR u.info03 LIKE ? OR u.info04 LIKE ? OR u.info05 LIKE ? ) ORDER BY u.userName ASC LIMIT ?
2018-08-30 12:58:47.905  WARN 9896 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2018-08-30 12:58:47.905 ERROR 9896 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null' at line 1
2018-08-30 12:58:47.909 DEBUG 9896 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<usergroup.restapi.models.UserDetails> usergroup.restapi.controller.UserSearchController.getGroupList(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
2018-08-30 12:58:47.910 DEBUG 9896 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<usergroup.restapi.models.UserDetails> usergroup.restapi.controller.UserSearchController.getGroupList(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
2018-08-30 12:58:47.911 DEBUG 9896 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<usergroup.restapi.models.UserDetails> usergroup.restapi.controller.UserSearchController.getGroupList(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
2018-08-30 12:58:47.916 DEBUG 9896 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Could not complete request

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:242) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
```

**My Native SQL Query as below:**

```
  @Query(
            value = "SELECT * FROM mail_user u  WHERE u.mailaddr LIKE %:mailaddr% AND u.userName LIKE %:userName% AND u.sendflag =:sendFlag AND "+"(u.info01 LIKE %:info01% OR u.info02 LIKE %:info02% OR u.info03 LIKE %:info03% OR u.info04 LIKE %:info04% OR u.info05 LIKE %:info05% )"+" ORDER BY u.userName ASC LIMIT :limit",nativeQuery = true
    )    public List<UserDetails> findByEmailAndUserAndFlag(@Param("mailaddr") String mailaddr,@Param("userName") String userName,@Param("sendFlag") String sendFlag,
            @Param("info01") String info01,@Param("info02") String info02,@Param("info03") String info03,@Param("info04") String info04,@Param("info05") String info05,
            @Param("limit") String limit
            );
```

Comment: You need to use https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html

Comment: Take a look at the Pageable class.

Comment: I do not want pagination....i need to limit my databsse results using offset and limit...values....

Comment: In your case it will generate exactly the same query... My guess is that you are passing wrong values and this is what's causing your issue... Try to execute the same query in your sql workbench/cli and observe the output. We can not help if you don't provide us the full stack trace + better explanation. Have you tried to explicitly stringifying the passed variables with single quotes like : *WHERE u.mailaddr LIKE '%:mailaddr%'*. Are you passing a composite string to the LIMIT clause?

Comment: executed below query at MYSQL and it is fetching proper results;SELECT * FROM mail_user u  WHERE u.mailaddr LIKE '%fu%' AND u.userName LIKE '%AS%' AND u.sendflag =1 AND (u.info02 LIKE '%ET%') ORDER BY u.userName ASC limit 2 ;  SQL Grammer error.@Query(
             value = "SELECT * FROM mail_user u  WHERE u.mailaddr LIKE %?1% AND u.userName LIKE %?2% AND u.sendflag =?3 AND "+"(u.info01 LIKE %?4% OR u.info02 LIKE %?5% OR u.info03 LIKE %?6% OR u.info04 LIKE %?7% OR u.info05 LIKE %?8% )"+" ORDER BY u.userName ASC limit ?9",nativeQuery = true
     )

Comment: Can you please try to remove the LIMIT clause from the native query (and the passed value for it). Let us know if the query is still failing...

Comment: If i remove limit clause it is working fine

Comment: And what is the exact string you are passing as a value to parameter ?9 .